# Find the sum to infinity of the series $1 + \frac{4}{3!} + \frac{6}{4!} + \frac{8}{5!} + \cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum the series to infinity

$$
1 + \frac{4}{3!} + \frac{6}{4!} + \frac{8}{5!} + \cdots 
$$

The general term is:

$$
u_n = \frac{2n}{(n+1)!}
$$

Not sure how to tackle this series.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{(n+1)!}&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}-2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\\
&=2\cdot\frac1{1!}=2.
\end{align}

Comment: You are basically observing that  $$\frac{2n}{(n+1)!}= \frac{2}{n!}-\frac{2}{(n+1)!}$$ which makes the series telescopic.